# antiforgeryToken to protect some actions on web api called from an angularjs app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, antiforgerytoken

I Have two web project in visualstudio.net 2013.

- One project i a WebApi2 with controllers and actions (simple)
- second project is a pure angularjs app with no MVC or WebApi (I started from an empty web project)

the angularjs application is calling service running on the webApi2 application.

I would like to know if it's possible to protect some actions of my controllers in my webapi2 application with an AntiforgeryToken. (antiforgeryToken attribute)
I found some post on the web but they require to use AntiForgery.GetTokens in my angular app and Therefore, I have to install all the mvc and razor... nuget packages.
(see this post : http://www.fredonism.com/archive/protect-your-web-api-from-csrf-attacks.aspx)

I would like to avoid this or is there a solution to use this antiforgerytoken with a minimal nuget packages installed ?

In other words : is it possible to protect some of my webapi controller actions with antiforgery token without using the MVC stuff.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's too late for this question, this will benefit others perhaps in the future.

First create a middleware to handle the requests in web api project.

```
public class AntiForgeryMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly string requestTokenCookieName;
        private readonly string[] httpVerbs = new string[] { "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "TRACE", "POST" };

        public AntiForgeryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string requestTokenCookieName)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.requestTokenCookieName = requestTokenCookieName;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {

            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

            if (path != null && path.ToLower().Contains("yourMethodThatGeneratesTheToken"))
            {
                if (httpVerbs.Contains(context.Request.Method, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);

                    context.Response.Cookies.Append(requestTokenCookieName, tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
                    {
                        HttpOnly = false
                    });


                } 
            }

            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Add the middleware in your Configure method of Startup.cs

`app.UseAntiforgeryTokenMiddleware("X-XSRF-TOKEN");`

In your angular interceptor, you may set the header as follows, by taking the cookie.

`var xsrfToken = this.cookieService.get("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfToken)`

in order to save the cookie you'll need to add `req = req.clone({ withCredentials: true });` at the top of the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

In your Empty ASP.NET Web application:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
```

By the time of this writing this will bring the following dependent packages as well:

- `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor`
- `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure`

and then in your `Index.aspx` which could be used to host your angular application:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%= System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml().ToString() %>
</body>
</html>
```

will generate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="QbixKR4muYghE6OnaBc2l8KqjumtU64-Zj7n7ktxyXeAhFx1FDgg43iJoeO9Eu94FvFxlBfpyKgFDAglSm4KAc0ZA-D30H-O7rSlq4x5nVA1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already tried that solution, but was wondering if there was a solution not to use razor at all. will try the solution proposed by @jack.the.ripper then will come with conclusions. thx

Comment: OP specifically said not using MVC libraries.

Comment: These libraries work in web forms as well.  `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` and `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml()` are usable in Web Forms.